# Im trying to make a giveaway command based in a tutorial i saw and it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js, undefined

As i said in the title i am getting this error, and I don't know how to fix it, but tutorials use the same thing and don't get this error. Pls help me i dont know what to do.

error:

> "Cannot read property 'start' of undefined"

```
const ms = require('ms')
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name : 'giveaway',
    execute : async(message, args ,client) => {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('You dont have manage messages permission.')

        const channel = message.mentions.channels.first()
        if(!channel) return message.channel.send('Please specify a channel')

        const duration = args[1]
        if(!duration) return message.channel.send('please enter a valid duration')

        const winners = args[2]
        if(!winners) return message.channel.send('Please specify an amount of winners')

        const prize = args.slice(3).join(" ")
        if(!prize) return message.channel.send('Please sepcify a prize to win')

        client.giveaways.start(channel, {
            time : ms(duration),
            prize : prize,
            winnerCount: winners,
            hostedBy: message.author,
            messages: {
                giveaway:  "Giveaway \@everyone",
                giveawayEnd: "Giveaway Ended \@everyone",
                timeRemaining: "Time Remaining **{duration}**",
                inviteToParticipate: "React with  to join the giveaway",
                winMessage: "Congrats {winners}, you have  won the giveaway",
                embedFooter: "Giveaway Time!",
                noWinner: "Could not determine a winner",
                hostedBy: 'Hosted by {user}',
                winners: "winners",
                endedAt: 'Ends at',
                units: {
                    seconds: "seconds",
                    minutes: "minutes",
                    hours: 'hours',
                    days: 'days',
                    pluralS: false
                }
            },
           
        })
        message.channel.send(`Giveaway is starting in ${channel}`)
    }
}
```

error line code: `client.giveaways.start(channel, {`

index.js:

```
client.giveaways = new GiveawaysManager(client, {
    storage : './giveaways.json',
    updateCountdownEvery : 5000,
    embedColor: '#D03600',
    reaction: ''
})
```

giveaways.json: `[]`

Execute:

```
try{
    command.execute(message,args, cmd, client, Discord);
} catch (err){
    message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
    console.log(err);
}

}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You are talking about an error line `client.giveaways.start(channel, {`, but that line isn't in the actual code you showed us, there however is `client.giveaways = start(channel, {`, did you mean that?

Comment: Oh sry i sent the wrong code yes its this one

Comment: Where do you pass in `client` to the `execute()` function?

Comment: In my event handler.

Comment: If you can show us how `client` gets from your `index.js` to the `execute()` function. But don't just dump in your whole program, include only the important parts.

Comment: Ok done you can check it

Comment: I have written an answer, you can check that out!

Comment: Thank you i will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `command.execute()` call, you are passing in `client` as the fourth parameter. But in your command file, where you export the giveaway command, `client` is the third parameter.

```js
module.exports = {
    name : 'giveaway',
    // Add cmd parameter here, so client is passed in correctly as the fourth parameter
    execute : async(message, args, cmd, client) => { ... }
}
```

Comment: ok i did that and now it says ReferenceError: channel is not defined in `client.giveaways.start(channel, {`

Comment: That is probably a different issue, as in your code, `channel` is defined before the call to `client.giveaways.start()`.

Comment: You should probably ask a new question as this concerns a different problem than the one you presented in your question.